# How to map a ResponseEntity<> getByName method with @PathVariable parameter?

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-data

I am new to Spring boot. I am having a problem with the below method to which support to get the raw by the name:

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AccountsResource {

    private final AccountsService service;

    @GetMapping("/accounts/{name}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getByName(@PathVariable String name){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.getByUsername(name));
    }

}
```

This is my AccountsService class:

```
public Accounts getByUsername(String username) {
    Optional<Accounts> byUsername = repository.findByUsername(username);
    return byUsername.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("User not found"));
}
```

and this is my Repository class for Acccounts:

```
@Repository
public interface AccountsRepository extends JpaRepository<Accounts, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM accounts where name = ?", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<Accounts> findByUsername(String username);

}
```

This is my Entity class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class Accounts extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;
    private String website;
    private String pContact;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="sales_rep_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private SalesRep sales;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "accounts")
    private List<Orders> orders;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<WebEvents> webEvents;

}
```

when I try to send the GET request with http://localhost:8081/api/accounts/1, I am getting:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-02-09T12:36:02.943+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/api/accounts/1"
}
```

With the IlligalStateException as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for '/api/accounts/1': {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.example.demo.web.rest.AccountsResource.getById(java.lang.Long), public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.example.demo.web.rest.AccountsResource.getByName(java.lang.String)}
```

I hope to get any suggestions on this regard. As I am new to this I appreciate any valid suggestions and links.

Comment: Is `getByName(@PathVariable String name)` the only method in your controller?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have to endpoints with the same path and the only difference is the type of the path variable the endpoints acepts, one requires a Long and the other a String and because you are invoking with a number spring cant figure if this number is a Long or is a String with a number character.

You should define a different path for the two endpoints

Comment: got it now. It is working now.